# Pyspark : How to concat two dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

df_1 :

| NBB1 |
| --- |
| 776 |

And df_2

| NBB2 |
| --- |
| 4867 |

I will to obtain this dataframe in Pyspark
df :

| NBB1 | NBB2 |
| --- | --- |
| 776 | 4867 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate/append multiple Spark dataframes column wise in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320699/how-to-concatenate-append-multiple-spark-dataframes-column-wise-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform a `crossJoin` between the two dataframes.
See below for details -

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(NBB1 = 776)])
df1.show()
#Output
+----+
|NBB1|
+----+
| 776|
+----+

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(NBB2 = 4867)])
df2.show()
#Output
+----+
|NBB2|
+----+
|4867|
+----+


df1.crossJoin(df2).show()
#Output
+----+----+
|NBB1|NBB2|
+----+----+
| 776|4867|
+----+----+
```